# Dynamic resource Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dynamic, resources

I'm have a directive for a search form. This gives you an template with `<form>` tag, automatized messages like "No results found" and an optional suggestion message like "You can search by name or id".

My problem it's that I want re utilize this directive for, for example, search books, authors or users in different pages of my application. I made resources (with ngResource) for them so I want pass dynamically this resources for my directive but I don't know how. My code is here:

```
angular
    .module('my-app')
    .directive('searchForm', searchForm)
    .controller('searchFormController', searchFormController);

function searchForm() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            info: '@'
        },
        controller: 'searchFormController',
        templateUrl: 'templates/directives/search-form.html'
    };
}

function searchFormController($scope, maybe_dynamic_resource_here) {
    $scope.results = [];

    $scope.searchSubmit = function(form){
        // do the search here calling to the dynamic resource
    };
}
```

My template:

```
<form name="searchform" ng-submit="searchSubmit(searchform)" novalidate>

<div class="wrapper-form center-block well">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="search" ng-model="search" name="search" class="form-control" required>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Search</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- mensajes -->
<div class="msg-info" ng-show="info && !searchform.$submitted">
    <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i> {{info}}
</div>

<div class="msg-info" ng-show="searchform.$submitted && !results.length">
    <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> No results found.
</div>
<!-- /mensajes -->

<card-of-results ng-repeat="result in results" />

</form>
```

And I use my directive like:

```
<search-form
    info="You can search by name or id."
/>
```

Maybe I had a wrong concept about all because I'm new with Angular, but the ideal for me it's call the directive like this:

```
<search-form
    info="You can search by name or id."
    resource="Books" <-- this is how I call the dynamic resource
/>
```

If there are a better way for do this, all help it's very appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You should read up about isolated scopes and data binding. The same way you bind `info`you will also have to bind `resource`, but using a `=` instead. Quite likely you might instead want a `&` to bind a function so you can trigger the search.

Answer (score 0):

i understand want you want to achive .i will try to provide a solution that i might have appiled

first i would create a factory for serach.

```
 .factory('SearchAPI', function ( $resource) {
     return {
         search: function () {
             return $resource('search/:path/:id', {}, {
                 books: {
                     method: 'GET',
                     params: { path: 'books' }
                 },
                 authors: {
                     method: 'GET',
                     params: { path: 'authors' }
                 },
                 users: {
                     method: 'GET',
                     params: { path: 'users' }
                 }
             })
         }
     }
 });
```

Now with in my controller the call will look like

**type will be book,author,user**

```
  $scope.searchSubmit = function(type){
      switch(type){
       case 'books' : 
         SearchAPI.search().books(function(data){

         });
        break;
        case 'authors' : 
           ......
    };
}
```

**or more simpler**

```
.factory('SearchAPI', function ( $resource) {
      return $resource('search/:path/:id', {}, {
              get: {
                  method: 'GET',
                  params: { path: '@path' }
              },
       });

});
```

and then your call will be

```
 $scope.searchSubmit = function(type){ 
       SearchAPI.get({path : type}).then(function(data){

        });
}
```